# How to query my table if there is an apostrophe in search term?

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, user-input

How can I search for a name in my table if there is an apostrophe in the name?

If I insert name with an apostrophe like `Ender's Game` in my search box, it gives an error.

I already tried solutions provided on stackoverflow, but I am not able to solve this.

Here is my code:

```
$string1  = $_GET['name'];
$quer = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE name = '$string1'";
$q = mysqli_query($conn, $quer);
```

If there is an apostrophe in `$_GET['name']`, an error is shown.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Never ever put user data directly into your queries. This leaves you open to SQL injection attacks. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php.

Comment: I am using preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\:\'\.\ ]/', '', $string1); to avoid special characters.

Comment: @vinay Don't do that.  Quoting is never perfect, and someone will find a way around it.  Let the driver handle that for you.

Comment: Is it still not safe? i already developed website and it is hard for me replace whole code with prep statement.

Comment: @vinay Correct.  For example, you're missing backspace.  Try running a query with a backspace at the end.  (This is just an example.  Don't try to improve the regex; instead, reference my answer below.)

Comment: you are right i will try to replace code with prep statement. thanks..

Comment: @vinay I added a solution to the bottom of my answer that can help with legacy code.  Save it as a last resort, but if your site is live and you need a quick fix, it should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice that you can expect to hear over and over again from knowledgeable StackOverflow volunteers is to use prepared statements to ensure query security and reliability.

For your case, I recommend the following snippet which not only safely executes your `SELECT` query, but also provides informative diagnostic/debugging checkpoints throughout the process and allows you to process the resultset - represented by an multi-dimensional associative array.

```
$_GET['name'] = "vinay's name";
$string1 = $_GET['name'];

if (!$conn = new mysqli("host", "user", "pass", "db")) {
    echo "Database Connection Error: " , $conn->connect_error;  // do not show this to public
} elseif (!$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM info WHERE name = ?")) {
    echo "Prepare Syntax Error: " , $conn->error;  // do not show this to public
} elseif (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $string1) || !$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Statement Error: " , $stmt->error;  // do not show this to public
}else{
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        var_export($row);  // do what you like here
    }
}
```

It is important to note that using `$stmt->bind_result($result)` (like in Zenexer's answer) will not work (generates `$result = NULL`) if the `info` table contains more than one column (I assume it will work with one column, but I didn't test); and it will generate a *Warning* because of an imbalance between the number of selected columns from `SELECT *` and the number of nominated variables.

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

If you want to enjoy the benefits of explicitly binding a result variable, you should specify your desired columns in the `SELECT` clause like this:

```
if (!$conn = new mysqli("host", "user", "pass", "db")) {
    echo "Database Connection Error: " , $conn->connect_error;  // do not show this to public
} elseif (!$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM info WHERE name = ?")) {
    echo "Prepare Syntax Error: " , $conn->error;  // do not show this to public
} else {
    if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $string1) || !$stmt->execute() || !$stmt->bind_result($id)) {
        echo "Statement Error: " , $stmt->error;  // do not show this to public
    } else {
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo "<div>$id</div>"; 
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: thank you for giving answer. your code helps me to understand the best way to write code.

Answer (score 4):

Code in that form is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).  Use [mysqli::prepare](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead:

```php
$string1  = $_GET['name'];

$quer = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE name = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($quer);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $string1);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

var_export($result);
```

If you're adapting legacy, insecure code, it may be faster to use [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).  This should be reserved as a last resort, but it's there if you need it, and it's better than a regex.

Comment: ok i will add  mysqli_real_escape_string for now but i will try to replace my code with prep statement. thanks for your help..